# does setState work on objects in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter widget that attempts to solve soduku grids. I have class called `SodukuSolver` which does all the calculations and provides a `List<String>` of the current results. I call `setState` to refresh the list, but it does not update the screen.

Below, I'll try to include as much of the relevant code as I can. Full source is at https://github.com/mankowitz/soduku

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: "Soduku solver", home: Soduku());
  }
}

class SodukuState extends State<Soduku> {
  SodukuSolver ss;
  List<String> _list;
  int _changes = 0;
  int _remaining = 81;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final String _starting =
        "750943002024005090300020000140089005093050170500360024000070009070400810400198057";
    ss = new SodukuSolver(_starting);
    _list = ss.getList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Soduku solver'), actions: <Widget>[
        // action button
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.directions_walk),
          onPressed: () {
            _iterate();
          },
        ),    
      ]),
      body: _buildGrid(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildGrid() {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1.0,
        child: Container(
          child: GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 9,
            ),
            itemBuilder: _buildGridItems,
            itemCount: 81,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }

  Widget _buildGridItems(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: GridTile(
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(_list[index]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _iterate() {
    setState(() {
      _changes = ss.iterateSoduku();
      _remaining = ss.empties();
      _list = ss.getList();
    });
  }
}

class Soduku extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SodukuState createState() => SodukuState();
}
```

So the problem is that `_iterate()` is being called, and I can use the debugger to see that the internal state of `SodukuSolver` is being updated and it is even passing `_list` correctly, but the grid on screen doesn't update, even though `_changes` and `_remaining` do update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your code in the initState() method as following

```
    @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();

        final String _starting =
 "750943002024005090300020000140089005093050170500360024000070009070400810400198057";
        ss = new SodukuSolver(_starting);
        _list = ss.getList();
      }
```

In your case, your list is not getting updated as setState() method will call your SodukuSolver() and ss.getList(); methods every time. because, setSate() ultimately calls build method to render every time.

So adding it inside your initState method will solve your issue. As it is getting called only once when the screen/route initialises.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating new `SodukuSolver` with same `_starting` every time the widget builds and then obtaining `_list` from it. So you are overriding changes from previous iteration.
Looks like `SodukuSolver` creation should be performed once. You can override `initState` in `SodukuState` and initialise `SodukuSolver` there or initialise it in the same place where it is declared